# Will this Transaction still arrive or was it stolen?

Tags: transactions

Was this Transaction stolen or did i make a mistake? ae6f689cb77a5eceea9eed5a91ce51f940fef2b8832946e747d0d0d788c3d9b3

Comment: What sort of situation is indicating to you that the money didn't arrive yet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is too localized, and unhelpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction `ae6f689cb77a5eceea9eed5a91ce51f940fef2b8832946e747d0d0d788c3d9b3` was confirmed in block 594768, paying a total of 0.00520707 BTC to the bitcoin address `37wefhkU2JDzQWJpmkTAB73AiQxBRXFQe`.

This transaction is confirmed, and at this point has several days worth of blocks on top of it, so it can definitely be considered immutable at this point.

If someone asked you to pay some BTC to this address, and now is pretending that it *"didn't arrive"*, *"was stolen"*, *"can't be accessed without some payment"*, etc, then you should be extremely wary of dealing with that individual in the future. This `37wefhkU2JDzQWJpmkTAB73AiQxBRXFQe` address **did** receive payment, it is not possible that it was *"stolen before being delivered"* or something like that.

Comment: thank you for the answer. what does immutable mean? can i still get the BTC?

Comment: Immutable more or less means 'non-changeable', aka the transaction cannot be changed or removed from the blockchain record. I do not know if you can 'get the BTC', because you have not given any information on what you are trying to do, which bitcoin addresses you own, etc.

Comment: sender is my blockchain wallet, receiver is a generated address of an account of mine

Comment: *"receiver is a generated address of an account of mine"* is this address generated for you by an exchange or some other online service? If yes, then they received the coins you sent.